How to parse search engine keywords input
I'm implementing a tool that lets users search for terms in texts. I'm currently focused on handling more complex input from the search.
The operators I am looking to support are :

| = OR
& = AND
^ = NOT
" " = Quotes to escape everything in a sequence
( ) = Parentheses for giving precedence to the encapsulated

This code should go into the Python backend that builds the query to the database engine, so I need a way to parse the query to transform the appropriate parts. Are there modules that would allow me to do that ?
I have tried looking at NLTK's logic package but it seems to do way too much things and it's not clear to me how to reduce it to these functions. I think I need something like NLTK's grammar trees but all I've found are packages that add grammatical tags and thus are tied to a language model.

Python Lex-Yacc might help you understand how to build a parser (if not use it to build your own, I haven't used it).

I agree with @Daviid - I would use PLY or SLY (the same author for both but PLY uses functions and SLY uses classes)

I would use PLY (Python Lex-Yacc) or SLY to parse it.
(PLY and SLY have the same author but PLY uses functions and SLY uses classes)
I took example calc.py from SLY and created code which converts query like
^(abc & def) | xyz

to nested list
['OR', ['NOT', ['AND', 'abc', 'def']], 'xyz']

which should be easy to use to generate SQL query
Other example(s):
(A&B)|(^C&D) ==> ['OR', ['AND', 'A', 'B'], ['AND', ['NOT', 'C'], 'D']]

I changed TEXT so it can catch A B C as one string without using " ".
And if you use "A B C" then it returns it as one string without " ".
But it allows to use " inside text (if there is no " at the beginning and at the end).
A"B"C & "F G H" & I J K ==> ['AND', ['AND', 'A"B"C', 'F G H'], 'I J K']
`
But it doesn't allow to use chars &|^!~() inside text. It would need some changes in TEXT and in functions.
"A&B" ==> ['AND', 'A', 'B']

I added

! as NOT because Python uses != as not equal so I was writing ! automatically in query
~ as NOT because I often use it in pandas for negations so sometimes I was writing ~ automatically in query


from sly import Lexer, Parser
import readline  # it allows to use keys `arrow up` `arrow down` to see previous queries in current session

class QueryLexer(Lexer):
    tokens = { TEXT }
    ignore = ' \t'
    literals = { '&', '|', '^', '!', '~', '(', ')'}

    # Tokens
    #TEXT = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
    TEXT = r'[^&|^!~()]{1,}'  # at least one char which is not in `literals`

    @_(r'\n+')
    def newline(self, t):
        self.lineno += t.value.count('\n')

    def error(self, t):
        print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
        self.index += 1

class QueryParser(Parser):
    tokens = QueryLexer.tokens

    precedence = (
        ('left', '&', '|', '!', '~'),
        ('right', '^'),
    )

    @_('expr')
    def statement(self, p):
        return p.expr

    @_('expr "&" expr')
    def expr(self, p):
        return ['AND', p.expr0, p.expr1]

    @_('expr "|" expr')
    def expr(self, p):
        return ['OR', p.expr0, p.expr1]

    @_('"^" expr', '"!" expr', '"~" expr')
    def expr(self, p):
        return ['NOT', p.expr]

    @_('"(" expr ")"')
    def expr(self, p):
        return p.expr

    @_('TEXT')
    def expr(self, p):
        return p.TEXT.strip(' ').strip('"')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lexer = QueryLexer()
    parser = QueryParser()
    while True:
        try:
            text = input('query > ')
        except EOFError:
            break
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
        if text:
            result = parser.parse(lexer.tokenize(text))
            if isinstance(result, str):
               print(f'text: >{result}<')  # I uses `> <` to see if there are spaces
            else:
               print(f'list: {result}')
               #import json
               #print(json.dumps(result, indent=1))


Here version with more modifications
Original version converts A & B & C & D to ['AND', ['AND', ['AND', 'A', 'B'], 'C'], 'D'], and new version can use function flatten() to create ['AND', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
If you send .flat or .notflat as query then it switch variable FLATTEN which decide if it should use flatten().
I also added function which tries to convert it to SQL query with  [VAR] LIKE "%text%"
and for list ['AND', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] it gives string
([VAR] LIKE "%A%" AND [VAR] LIKE "%B%" AND [VAR] LIKE "%C%" AND [VAR] LIKE "%D%") 

So you have to only replace [VAR] with your variable.
But I don't know if I should add % automatically or user should ask A% & %B because it allows to check if text starts with A and ends with B
Eventually user could use A* & *B & C and code should convert it to A% AND %B AND %C% (add % automatically if there is no * at both sides.
I added also function which saves history in file and read it at next start.
I added also json to display data as
[
 "AND",
 "A",
 [
  "OR",
  "B",
  "C",
  "D"
 ],
 [
  "NOT",
  "X"
 ]
]


I added function .history (and shortcut .h) to see history.
I also added function to select field like day:*h*day & title:Hello
which gives (day LIKE "%h%day" AND title LIKE "%Hello%")

from sly import Lexer, Parser
import readline
import atexit
import os
import json

#COLOR = '\x1b[1;31m' # red
COLOR = '\x1b[1;32m' # green
RESET = '\x1b[m'

BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
HISTORY_PATH = os.path.join(BASE, ".history")

MAKE_FLAT = True
DEFAULT_VAR = '[VAR]'

class QueryLexer(Lexer):
    tokens = { TEXT }
    ignore = ' \t'
    literals = { '&', '|', '^', '!', '~', '(', ')'}

    # Tokens
    #WORD   = r'[^&|^!~()"]{1,}'      # at least one char which is not in `literals`
    #PHRASE = r'"[^"]*"'          
    TEXT = r'"[^"]*"|[^&|^!~()]{1,}'  # at least one char which is not in `literals`

    @_(r'\n+')
    def newline(self, t):
        self.lineno += t.value.count('\n')

    def error(self, t):
        print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
        self.index += 1

class QueryParser(Parser):
    tokens = QueryLexer.tokens

    precedence = (
        ('left', '&', '|', '!', '~'),
        ('right', '^'),
    )

    @_('expr')
    def statement(self, p):
        return p.expr

    @_('expr "&" expr')
    def expr(self, p):
        result = ['AND', p.expr0, p.expr1]
        if MAKE_FLAT:
            result = flatten(result)
        return result

    @_('expr "|" expr')
    def expr(self, p):
        result = ['OR', p.expr0, p.expr1]
        if MAKE_FLAT:
            result = flatten(result)
        return result

    @_('"^" expr', '"!" expr', '"~" expr')
    def expr(self, p):
        return ['NOT', p.expr]

    @_('"(" expr ")"')
    def expr(self, p):
        return p.expr

    @_('TEXT')
    def expr(self, p):
        return p.TEXT.strip(' ')


def flatten(data):
    key = data[0]
        
    values = []
    
    for item in data[1:]:
        if isinstance(item, list) and item[0] == key:
            values.extend(item[1:])
        else:
            values.append(item)
        
    return [key, *values]

def generate(data):
    if isinstance(data, str):
        text = data
        var  = DEFAULT_VAR

        if not text.startswith('"') and (':' in text):
            var, text = text.split(':', 1)
            print(var, text)
            
        text = text.strip('"')
        
        if '*' in text:
           text = text.replace('*', '%')
        
        if '%' not in text:
           text = f'%{text}%'
           
        return f'{var} LIKE "{text}"'

    key = data[0]
    values = data[1:]
    
    if key in ['NOT']:
        text = data[1]
        var  = DEFAULT_VAR
        
        if not text.startswith('"') and (':' in text):
            var, text = text.split(':', 1)
            print(var, text)

        text = text.strip('"')
        
        if '*' in text:
            text = text.replace('*', '%')
           
        if '%' not in text:           
            text = f'%{text}%'
           
        return f'{var} NOT LIKE "{text}"'
    
    if key in ['AND', 'OR']:
        key = f' {key} '  # add spaces
        
        # convert to `var LIKE value`
        values = [generate(item) for item in values]
        # join using AND, OR
        text = key.join(values)
    else:
        text = str(data)
        
    return f'({text})'  # add ( )
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # read history at the beginning    
    try:
        readline.read_history_file(HISTORY_PATH)
        readline.set_history_length(1000)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    # write history at the end
    atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, HISTORY_PATH)
        
    lexer = QueryLexer()
    parser = QueryParser()

    number = 0    
    while True:
        try:
            number += 1
            text = input(f'[{number}] {COLOR}query >{RESET} ')
        except EOFError:
            break
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
        if text:
            result = parser.parse(lexer.tokenize(text))
            if isinstance(result, str):
                print(f'text: >{result}<')  # I uses `> <` to see if there are spaces
                cmd = result.split(' ')
                if cmd[0] in ('.history', '.h') :
                    for index in range(1, readline.get_current_history_length()+1):
                        print(f'[{index}]', readline.get_history_item(index))
                elif cmd[0] in ('.flat', '.f'):
                    MAKE_FLAT = True
                    print('MAKE_FLAT:', MAKE_FLAT)
                elif cmd[0] == ('.notflat', '.nf'):
                    MAKE_FLAT = False
                    print('MAKE_FLAT:', MAKE_FLAT)
                elif cmd[0] in ('.var', '.v'):
                    if len(cmd) > 1:
                        DEFAULT_VAR = cmd[1]
                    print('DEFAULT_VAR:', DEFAULT_VAR)
                else:
                    print(f'data: {result}')
                    print(json.dumps(result, indent=1))
                    print(generate(result))
            else:
                print(f'data: {result}')
                print(json.dumps(result, indent=1))
                print(generate(result))


.notflat

.flat


Well this is not for SQL so the generation you added doesn't fit what I'd need but I can certainly use it as a good basis for what I wanted to do. Thanks
